# Set custom font (TypeFace) in dialog in Android

Tags: android, dialog, typeface

I'd like to change the font in textview which is in dialog:

```
dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialog_box_title_text)).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf"));
```

But every time I get the runtime exception:

> E/AndroidRuntime(4475): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Do you have any idea what is wrong? Because normally it works fine. Problem is only when  try to change the font in dialog.

Comment: are you using correct path..for font.ttf

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this, and let me know what happen.

```
((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_box_title_text)).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf"));
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much :) You have saved a few hours of my life :)

Comment: Saved by You... Thanx

Answer (score 2):

For a `DialogFragment` this will work (I'm targeting SDK 19, and I have minSDK 14) as long as you put the font file in your `assets()` folder.

So if you are running ice cream sandwich (ICS) and later try this :

```
@Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Call to the Super Class, performing the default behavior
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Change the Dialog Title Text Typeface
    ((TextView)getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setTypeface(
        Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Roboto-Thin.ttf"));
}
```